# Apache Shiro - form based authentication doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: security, shiro

I have got problems with implementing form based authentication. I created a simple web application and before openening a page (/jsp/index.jsp) I want to check the user's rights and open a login page if it is necessary.

Unfortunately if I try to open the link of index.jsp (*http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/jsp/index.jsp*) the index.jsp is turning up immediately but I expected the login.jsp first! Here are the importan files:

Shiro.ini

```
[main]
# specify login page
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
# name of request parameter with username; if not present filter assumes 'username'
authc.usernameParam = user
# name of request parameter with password; if not present filter assumes 'password'
authc.passwordParam = passw
# does the user wish to be remembered?; if not present filter assumes 'rememberMe'
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
[url]
# enable authc filter for all application pages
/jsp/** = authc
[users]
adminstrator=throttling,Administrator
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="starter" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This the directory structure of **maven project / src / main**

```
├───java
├───resources
│       log4j.properties
│       Shiro.ini
│
└───webapp
    │   login.jsp
    │
    ├───jsp
    │       index.jsp
    │
    └───WEB-INF
        │   web.xml
        │
        └───lib
```

I added these two dependencies to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
      <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
      <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hopefully I wrote any of the important information! Could anyone help me why it doesn't work for me?
Thanks, V.

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c]: %m%n
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.quartz=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext=INFO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I made a mistake in the shiro.ini. I wrote [url] instead of [urls]...
Sorry again and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If what you've shown here is exact, then your problem is probably that Shiro by default looks for 'shiro.ini' whereas you have created 'Shiro.ini'.  There is likely also a message in your logs to the effect of 'ShiroFilter can't locate the ini file.'

Also note that you will need to make sure that authc is applied to login.jsp in order for the login to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked it doesn't matter that the 'Shiro.ini' or 'shiro.ini' name is used it is working with both.
Could you tell me how I could apply the authc to login.jsp? Thanks!

Comment: I applied the authc to login.jsp but no success... How could I debug the shiro? I added the log4j.properties but I sis not see more logs.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is working with both"?. If it's in the resources directory that means that it is being loaded from the classpath.  Java's classpath resource access is case sensitive.  Another thing you could try is specifying the "shiroConfigLocations" explicitly in your web.xml.
 <context-param>
  <param-name>shiroConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:Shiro.ini</param-value>
 </context-param>